# Is it bad practice to use window.location.replace from within AJAX 'success' callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it bad practice to perform a redirection within an jQuery AJAX request?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myurl",       
    success : function(response) {  
        window.location.replace('MYNEWPAGE');
    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
```

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour in an app and I think this is the issue.

Comment: If you're reloading the page after your ajax call, it might be simpler to do a simple form POST and a redirect.

Comment: That doesn't allow for failure without a page reload, and it doesn't allow for other-than-POST operations.  I just did the same thing yesterday for a DELETE where the page should only redirect if the DELETE was successful.  I'm also interested in whether this construction might cause problems (in my case, I don't see any).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`location.replace()` doesn't store the current page into the browser history, the user can't use the back button to go back onto the page. You should use `location.assign(URL)` or `location.href = URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Should only use `window.location.href = "whatever"` to change the url. Note that this will cause you to postback your whole page, strange behavior may come from your load events on new page firing unexpectedly, including other ajax events that might also set window.location.href - you could theoretically get deadlock with stuff just continuing to send you to new pages (careful).